# Why is only contravariance allowed for method input parameters according to the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: methods, input, parameters, contravariance, liskov-substitution-principle

I was trying to find good examples of why *contra-variance* is the only variance allowed for method input parameters according to the Liskov Substitution Principle, but until now none of the examples has completely answered ,y doubts.

I was trying to build a counter-example that could prove the statement above, but I am not sure about it. Suppose we have the following classes:

```
class Z {...}

class X extends Z {...}

class Y extends X {...}

class A { 
    void m(X x);
    ...
}

class B extends A {
    void m(Y y);  // Overriding inherited method m using covariance (by contradiction)
    ...
}
```

Now, suppose I have the following situation:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b; // Allowed because b is also an A object (B extends A)
```

Now, since the static type of `a` is `A`, theoretically we should be able to pass `X` objects to the method `m` on `a` (not sure what the LSP says about this):

```
a.m(new X());
```

At runtime (not sure what the LSP says about runtime and compile-time), on the other hand, this would fail, because `a` is actually pointing to a `B` object, but the method overridden in `B` `m` only accepts `Y` objects, which are of subtype `X`.

If we had allowed contra-variance instead, for example by overriding `m` in `B` by specifying the type of the parameter as `Z` or `X`, none of this would happen.

This is for now my (and my friend's) only explanation of why we are only allowed to use contra-variance for method parameters.

Is my explanation correct? Are there other situations that can explain this concept more in detail? Concrete examples are appreciated!

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct. There are other cases, I guess they are just variations of the same. You need to be able to treat B as an A, and it shall behave like an A, that's the contract of inheritance. This is not a real question, since you answer it yourself. It's more like starting a discussion about the topic. This will be closed on Stackoverflow, because it is a Q&A site.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger This is not a discussion, these are just my thoughts, which I am sharing with you in order to understand where I am wrong or where I am right. That's why I am asking: "Is my explanation correct?". If you like to be a funny guy, you failed this time.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, I just don't know how this question could be answered in a way that fits in Stackoverflows concepts. I'm just trying to explain this. These are your thoughts; where is the question then? If it is: "Am I right?", you expect an answer like "yes, you're right" (since this is the case). Everything else is a discussion.

Comment: I think you pretty much covered it. I have nothing to add.